# Approximate a slowly varying polynomial

Tags: optimization, deep-learning

I am dealing with a more complex problem, but I think it can be reduced to the minimal exercise of approximating the function f(t) = 1-10^(-4)t^2 with a neural network. I want to approximate it in the time interval [0,10], for example, and here the function varies very little.

The question is hence: how do you deal with neural networks that need to approximate functions with small coefficients?

I have tested various neural network architectures and this small value seems hard to capture. Actually my goal would be to have something even smaller than 10^(-4).